# Why is a list not allowed with format strings?

Tags: python, string, format-specifiers

Why is a tuple (or dict) mandatory for use with a format string:

```
"%s %d" % ("text", 42)
```

What would be the disadvantage of the following?

```
"%s %d" % ["text", 42]
```

Comment: Because the syntax was [defined to use a tuple or mapping object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). The same reason you wouldn't use double quotes to define an integer literal. They very well could have made it use lists but why should it?

Comment: Good question. I don't know, but I suspect it has to do with the mutability of lists

Comment: No explanation given in [the source](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/stringobject.c#L4614). I'm guessing the reason is "because it would require a nontrivial amount of work to implement, and not enough people want it"

Comment: @Jeff My question is why not?

Comment: It is kind of odd that the rule is if it is a tuple, then unpack, otherwise call `__str__`. If the rule was to call `__str__` if there is only one format specification, and try to unpack if there is more than one, then it would work naturally for anything reasonable.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I suspected that to. Something like "is not hashable". But... how would that make a difference?

Comment: My guess is to make it easy to pass as `*args` on to a C `printf()`-like internal function.

Comment: Why not? Any reason for introducing dialects? Someone use parentheses, and others use bracket? More confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, but I expect it's because GvR wanted to minimise the number of different types `T` for which `'my object is: %s' % T(...)` fails. It's bad enough that it fails for `namedtuple`s ;-)

That is to say, allowing `'%s %s' % [1,2]` creates an extra trap for the unwary, because it prevents you formatting `[1,2]` itself with the `%s` format.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are faster to access than lists, which makes it the default

Comment: does that really matter? After all we are formatting strings, which is never fast, i.e. should never be done in time critical code. Furthermore, usually one does that with 1 to 10 elements in the tuple.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the usage of a tuple in formatting a string  is to resolve ambiguities. That is, suppose you have an immutable object such as a list or a dict, these objects are likely to change in the future and so the formatting may fail or it may be formatted not the way you expected it to be! Indeed the usage of a tuple is much more clearer than using a list, that's because a tuple cannot be changed in-palace like a list.

For example, consider the following code:

```
T = ("spam", "ham")

s = "%s and %s" % T
```

since the left object is a tuple, you can make sure this will never be changed in-place by an operation when the program is run and so you can have a peace of mind about that. However, not to say using tuples are completely safe as you can do something like `T += ("holy cow",)` and thus you'll add a third item to your tuple that will make the expression erroneous. Tuples though are less likely to change than lists because they're immutable objects. A list might be changed anywhere and who knows where and when that list might change in a million-line program?

Notice what happens when we use lists instead here:

```
L = ["spam", "ham"]
L.append("Ice-cream")        #line 103984.. above "%s and %s" % L 

s = "%s and %s" % L              #Error, three values in L
```

You might think that `L` contains only `"spam"` and `"ham"`, but indeed `L`contains another object that was added from an operation when the program ran. You might detect this error yourself in a smaller system, but think what if the list `L` was used for state retention between functions in a gigantic system, how would you know its value or the changes that might occur? Even worse, you might want to pass `s` to a function to process the formatted string in a certain way, your function here will fail immediately if it depends on certain string format. And if doesn't except a specific string format, it may process the operation that your intend upside down.

This can be ambiguous as you need to trace through all the codes; certainly this is a tedious task in large systems. Lists aren't guarded from changes, it's the other way around, you're supposed to change and manipulate lists as you would. because the list can be changed from time to time, Python uses only a tuple in the formatting expression to disallow this confusion. Generally, tuples are a type of a list, but they're constants, you can't change them in place. this literally simplify the operation of debugging a program.

Comment: I think the point you make with changing the list between initialisation and usage is valid. Unfortunately there is a lot of other aspects which have little to do with the question or are confusing...